# shows only rows with prices that satisfy the condition (compared to recent price row)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:
COINS with coin name and current prices
ALERTS with alerts set by users

I want shows results of alerts triggered,

i.e. if coin CAKE goes to 21 alert "H 20" (higher 20) will triggered

if coin CAKE goes under 11 alert "L 11) (lower 11) will triggered

I can do it with a lot of queries but i want do it with just one...

Problems:

- get only most recent date coin prices (from table COINS)
- get result comparing ALERTS sets and current prices

```
table ALERTS

id | user  |  coin  |  se  |  pricealert
----------------------------------------
1  | 15    | cake   |  H   |  20
2  | 15    | cake   |  L   |  11
3  | 21    | sbdo   |  H   |  8000
4  | 15    | bnb    |  H   |  300
5  | 21    | bnb    |  H   |  280
7  | 15    | bnb    |  L   |  200
8  | 15    | mds    |  L   |  5000

table COINS (* most recent date)
coin   | value   | data
---------------------------------
cake   |    12   | 2021-03-22
cake   |    13   | 2021-03-23
**cake |    14   | 2021-03-24**
bnb    |   250   | 2021-03-22
bnb    |   270   | 2021-03-23
**bnb  |   330   | 2021-03-24**
mds    |  5900   | 2021-03-23
**mds  |  4700   | 2021-03-24**
sbdo   |  6000   | 2021-03-23
**sbdo |  6700   | 2021-03-24**

wanted RESULTS
id | user | coin   | se    | pricealert  | currentprice
4  | 15   | bnb    |  H    |   300       |   330
5  | 21   | bnb    |  H    |   280       |   330
8  | 15   | mds    |  L    |  5000       |  4700
```

I can think to query one by one, but i want do it in just 1 query
this is for get recent values of coin (not best solution i think)

```
SELECT  MAX(data), valore, coin 
FROM coins WHERE data>(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  
GROUP BY coin
```

this is from select results?

```
SELECT * 
FROM results 
WHERE (currentprice<pricealert and se='L') 
   OR (currentprice>pricealert and se='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select* from (
   select *, rank() over (partition by coin order by date desc) rn 
   from coins 
) c
join alerts a
 on a.coin = c.coin
 and rn = 1
 and ( 
       (c.value > a.pricealert and a.se='H')
       OR (c.value < a.pricealert and a.se='L')
      )
```

seems like your mysql version is old and doesn't support row_number or rank() window function, so you can use query below instead:

```
select c.* 
from (
   select coin, max(date) date
   from coins 
   group by coin
) mc
join coin on c.coin = mc.coin and c.date = mc.date
join alerts a on a.coin = c.coin
 and ((c.value > a.pricealert and a.se='H')
   OR (c.value < a.pricealert and a.se='L')
      )
```

Comment: got an error.. i never saw this "row_number over partition" maybe on my mysql server doesn't work this command?
alternatives?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by coin order by data desc) rn
   from coins
) c join ' at line 2

Comment: here is [doc ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7 apache server shared hosting

Comment: ok your version doesn't support those window functions , see updated asnwer